# Why do the Chassidim require explicit mention?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In the amidah, the prayer for our welfare includes specific mention of Chassidim, but not of Litvaks, Sefardim, etc.:

> עַל הַצַּדִּיקִים וְעַל הַחֲסִידִים. וְעַל זִקְנֵי עַמְּךָ בֵּית
> יִשרָאֵל. וְעַל פְּלֵיטַת סופְרֵיהֶם. וְעַל גֵּרֵי הַצֶּדֶק.
> וְעָלֵינוּ.
>
> *On behalf of the righteous, on behalf of the Chassidim, on behalf of
> the elders of Your people, the House of Israel, on behalf of their
> surviving halls of learning, on behalf of the righteous converts, and
> on our own behalf:,*

Why is that?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: @NBZ, because it must be stated unequivocally that Chassidim are not heretics (despite the insistence of minhagei haGr"a)

Answer (score 5):

It seems pretty clear to me that at least the Litvaks are referenced in Al HaTzaddikim "The Correct Ones"

Comment: +1 Kasha: In according with your answer, I suppose Yemenites are *ziknei amecha*. And converts are of course *gerei hatzedek*. But then, who are we (*alenu*)?

Comment: Gut gefrekt.  I gotta think about that :)

Comment: That's because Alenu are the litvaks. See Kol Bo on Otzar Hatiflus.

Comment: @Yitzchak, kal vachomer, the tzadikim must be the Yekkes. Wait, that doesn't work, then alenu refers to Litvaks: I myself am not Litvisch, so I am excluding myself!

Answer (score 3):

The people that you think were excluded are actually included. The problem is that the author of this *bracha* couldn't enumerate all of them, because then, the *Shmeneh esreh* would be far longer than it already is.

So instead, all these other groups were included in the phrase פְּלֵיטַת סופְרֵיהֶם meaning "Those that were expelled from their countings". I.e. - they couldn't be included in the enumeration of the rest of the group.

What's puzzling, though is that the righteous of the Gerer ARE mentioned. I don't get that at all.

Comment: +1 But that just begs my question: The reighteous and the elders is general, while Chassidim is so specific.

Comment: @NBZ - Look at the order of the words. It's in descending order of importance. First tzadikim - their righteous. Chassidim - O.K. many o fthem are righteous, but here and there ... maybe not. Then the old people - they're getting old, they can't do as much as the others. What's a bit puzzling is that they specifically mention the righteous of the Gerer sect - I don't get that at all.